# How do I populate an html text input field based on an html select option

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on an `html` page that will allow users to get pre-populated text filled into the text input field, based on the option they select.  I'm trying to do this via `javascript` but I can't get the function to "fire" when I do an `onchange` within the select input field.

Trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong, either with the function, the innerHTML, or both.

Example code I'm working on below:

`HTML`

```
<label for='accountg'>Goal</label>
    <select id="accountg" name="accountg" style="border-radius:1px;border:1px solid #003399;font-size:14px;width:50px;" onchange="accountSelect()">
        <option value=''></option>      
        <option value='1'></option> 
        <option value='2'></option>
        <option value='3'></option>
        <option value='4'></option>
        <option value='5'></option>
    </select>

<input type="text" id="account1" name="account1" style="width:900px;" title="140 character maximum" />
```

`JAVASCRIPT`

```
function accountSelect() {
var aSelect = document.getElementById('accountg').value;
var account1 = '';

    if(aSelect == '') {

    } else if(aSelect == 1){

        if(account1 == '')
            {
                var act1 = 'Outlines written policies and procedures to ensure consistent adherence by staff.';
                document.getElementById('account1').innerHTML = act1;
            } else {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of of a complex `if` structure, store the data (the texts to add) in an array, and use the value of the select element as an index to fetch a text from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input>` doesn't have an inner content, it has a `value` though:

```
document.getElementById('account1').value = act1;
```